# Why do some webpages work on wifi but not on cellular data?

Tags: ios, cellular-data

One script of a webpage is failing in iOS. I thought it was related to the new *"prevent cross-site tracking"* setting, but it's because of the network being used!

**It works on a wifi network, but it doesn't if it is using mobile/cellular data**. I can't imagine or find why, so I'm looking for some idea between you, the Apple experts.

Comment: In theory, it could have been https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Save-Data. At least that document, however, says it's not (yet) implemented in Safari, so I'm just leaving it here for future reference, or maybe someone knows if the documentation is out of date.

Comment: I have similar issues from time to time. It may be the cellular data connection is not robust enough to handle that page. EG even if you have 3-4 bars data usage on that cell may be high thus reducing your effective throughput.... maybe...

Comment: I think there are some browser settings which when enabled reduce data usage when not on wifi, but reducing the quality of webpages.